# Visual Basic How to check if a variable changed in 5 minutes?

Tags: vb.net

> here is the example:

```
    Dim Cchanges As Integer

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    If 'some kind a solution here' Then
        MsgBox("there is no changes made in 5 minutes")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Label1.Text = Cchanges
End Sub
```

and any other solutions will be appraciated.

Comment: You need another variable that stores the value of Cchanges when you started the timer.

Answer (score -1):

This should give you what you need:

```
Private timer As New Timer(TimerTick, Nothing, TimeSpan.Zero, New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1))
Private lastMinute As Integer = 1

Private Sub TimerTick(state As Object)
    Dim minute = DateTime.Now.Minutes
    If minute <> lastMinute AndAlso minute Mod 5 = 0 Then

        Select Case (String.Compare(txtOldValue.text, txtNewValue.text)
            Case < 0
                MsgBox("Your old value is smaller than your new value or is null.")
            Case = 0
                MsgBox("The values are equal")
            Case > 0 
                MsgBox("Your new value is smaller than your old value or is null."
        End Select
        lastMinute = minute

    End If
End Sub
```